# Why when I copy javascript code word for word and encapsulate it in my own html (which is exact except for containing propper tags) it wont function

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

src: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/3d-perspective-projection-canvas-javascript

the code below is code I copied and put inside propper tags. 
some css is missing from source that i dont know how to add.
is there excessive information in my html?

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var fov = 250;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var pixels = [];
for (var x = -250; x < 250; x += 5)
    for (var z = -250; z < 250; z += 5)
        pixels.push({
            x: x,
            y: 40,
            z: z
        });

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    var imagedata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    var i = pixels.length;
    while (i--) {
        var pixel = pixels[i];
        var scale = fov / (fov + pixel.z);
        var x2d = pixel.x * scale + w / 2;
        var y2d = pixel.y * scale + h / 2;
        if (x2d >= 0 && x2d <= w && y2d >= 0 && y2d <= h) {
            var c = (Math.round(y2d) * imagedata.width + Math.round(x2d)) * 4;
            imagedata.data[c] = 0; //red
            imagedata.data[c + 1] = 255; //green
            imagedata.data[c + 2] = 60; //blue
            imagedata.data[c + 3] = 255; //alpha
        }
        pixel.z -= 1;
        if (pixel.z < -fov) pixel.z += 2 * fov;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imagedata, 0, 0);
}
setInterval(render, 1000 / 30);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>exe</title>
    <style> html, body { margin:0;padding:0;overflow: hidden; } 
</style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Run the code and you get an error in the console. Seems like you haven't copied everything.

Comment: You have `ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);` but have not declared/set `ctx` anywhere in your code... I would go back and look for that from your source

Comment: This happens a lot nowadays.  The original code may be relying on an external library.  Check what scripts the original code is importing.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few changes and now it works (sort of).
The vars w and h weren't declared. Also the double loop for x and z was missing the curly brackets and renamed context to ctx.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var fov = 250;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var pixels = [];

for (var x = -250; x < 250; x += 5) {
  for (var z = -250; z < 250; z += 5) {
    pixels.push({
      x: x,
      y: 40,
      z: z
    });
  }
}

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  var imagedata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
  var i = pixels.length;

  while (i--) {
    var pixel = pixels[i];
    var scale = fov / (fov + pixel.z);
    var x2d = pixel.x * scale + w / 2;
    var y2d = pixel.y * scale + h / 2;

    if (x2d >= 0 && x2d <= w && y2d >= 0 && y2d <= h) {
      var c = (Math.round(y2d) * imagedata.width + Math.round(x2d)) * 4;
      imagedata.data[c] = 0; //red
      imagedata.data[c + 1] = 255; //green
      imagedata.data[c + 2] = 60; //blue
      imagedata.data[c + 3] = 255; //alpha
    }
    pixel.z -= 1;
    if (pixel.z < -fov) pixel.z += 2 * fov;
  } //while



  ctx.putImageData(imagedata, 0, 0);
}


setInterval(render, 1000 / 30);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong with the original code and what you did to fix it. Readers shouldn't have to do their own comparison to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you  @Barmar for your comments. I've added the changas I've made

Comment: While I agree that they're a good idea, the curly braces for the `x` and `z` loops aren't needed, because they just contain one statement.

Comment: The other important change was that you renamed `context` to `ctx`.